# How could we tell this element has zero trace? (Galois Theory)

Tags: galois-theory, field-trace

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284149/galois-groups-of-mathbbq-alpha-for-alpha-sqrtab-sqrtc-where-a) earlier and I was quite confused by Ege's answer when he said 'Moreover, they have zero trace.' I was wondering how could we tell that? So my question is how did we tell that
$ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $ has trace $0$?

I am assuming by the word 'trace', we are talking about the sum of all the roots of the minimal polynomial of $ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $ but I was really unsure on how to find its minimal polynomial. So I was wondering is there a slick way of seeing this comment by Ege?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: The explanation of the zero trace is there in the answer, considering those elements of the form $ x + y \sqrt{d} $ for $ x, y, d \in \mathbf Q $ . What beyond this are you not following?

Comment: @fundamentalform Thank you for your comment. Ege said that $ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $ has trace $0$ and so $x=0$. In particular why does $ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $ have trace $0$ is my question. I think you are understanding this the wrong way round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to calculate the minpoly. The conjugates are

- $\sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}}$
- $\sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}}$
- $- \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} - \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}}$
- $- \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} - \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}}$

these all cancel so you get 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! how did we determine that these four (well two actually) are the conjugates? Do we just apply Galois action on $ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $ individually? And we are allowed to do this because the Galois group also permutes the roots of the min poly of $ \sqrt{a + b \sqrt{c}} + \sqrt{a - b \sqrt{c}} $?