# Is $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am stuck at the following seemingly simple problem: is Is $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

(Context: I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}})$ is an extension of degree 2).

So far, I assumed it is not, and argued with contradiction. Suppose $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} = a + b\sqrt{2}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then squaring both sides we have that 
$$
2 + \sqrt{2} = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt{2} + 2b^2, 
$$
and hence 
$$
2 - a^2 - 2b^2 = (2ab-1)\sqrt{2}. 
$$
Now if $2ab-1 \neq 0$, we get $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction. So suppose we are in the case $2ab = 1$, I don't know how to proceed to derive a contradiction in this case. Is there a general strategy to do this? I notice that then 
$$
a^2 = 2-2b^2, 
$$
so $a = \sqrt{2(1-b^2)} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-b^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/575171/721644)

Comment: [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367383/721644)

Comment: Do you know any algebraic number theory? Your solution can definitely be made to work, but it saves time to use a few facts from ANT.

Comment: Actually, basic abstract algebra is enough, i.e., to know what the field degree $[L:K]$ is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(X^2-2)^2-2=0$

$P(X)=X^4-4X^2+2=0$ Eisenstein is irreducible implies that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}:\mathbb{Q}]=4$

Comment: That's a nice approach! I wonder whether the approach I took works at all? (although this one is surely quicker)

Answer (score 2):

We know that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}):\Bbb Q]=4$, but $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}):\Bbb Q]=2$. Hence $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ cannot be in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Reference:

[Galois Group of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575171/galois-group-of-sqrt2-sqrt2-over-mathbbq?noredirect=1&lq=1)