# Determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\Bbb Q$ and find its Galois group over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\Bbb Q$ and find its Galois group over $\Bbb Q$.

Computed and obtained $p(x)=x^4-4x^2+2$ has $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ as a root. $p$ is clearly monic and irreducible (Eisenstein), thus $p$ is the required minimal polynomial.

$p$ has roots : $\pm \sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{2}}$ . Since $p$ has no multiple root in its splitting field say, $K$ , thus $K|\Bbb Q$ is Galois.

$|Gal(K| \Bbb Q)|= [K:\Bbb Q]=4$

I don't seem to find any intermediate extension $\Bbb Q \subset M \subset K$ s.t. $[K:M]=2$ other than $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ . In that case, $Gal(K| \Bbb Q)=\Bbb Z_4$ .  **Here my argument is shaky** .

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Your polynomial seems to come up in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45893/how-to-find-the-galois-group-of-a-polynomial

Comment: There are many duplicates on this site, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575171/galois-group-of-sqrt2-sqrt2-over-mathbbq) and the related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Set $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}$ and $b=\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}$. Clearly $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is fixed under $a\mapsto -a, b\mapsto -b$, as $$\sqrt2=a^2-2=2-b^2=ab$$ and this permutation has order $2$.

Hint: What about sending $a$ to $b$? Where does $b$ go? Which order does this element of the Galois group have? What is the fixed subfield?

More details: Note that $a^2-2-ab=0$. Any automorphism $f$ of $K$ must respect this, which is to say
$$
f(a)^2-2-f(a)f(b)=0
$$
So, if $f(a)=b$, what do we get? 
$$
b^2-2-bf(b)=0\\
-(2-b^2)-bf(b)=0\\
-\sqrt2=bf(b)
$$
Among $\pm a, \pm b$, only $-a$ has this property. Which means that if $f(a)=b$, we must have $f(b)=-a$, meaning $f$ has order $4$. This means the Galois group must be $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: You set $a$ and $b$ to the same thing. Is that right?

Comment: @TonyK No, it isn't. Thanks.

Comment: Can you kindly give a detailed answer? I am totally new to Galois theory

Comment: Yeah got it, $\sigma(a)=b$, has order > 2, we are done!