# How to construct Automorphisms in Galois Group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am studying Galois theory at the moment and having some serious troubles in calculating the Galois Groups in certain problems

For eg : I need to show to that $\mathbb{Q} \sqrt{2+ \sqrt2}$ is a cyclic quartic field of over $\mathbb{Q}$, meaning it is a cyclic Galois Group.

Now, the irreducible polynomial corresponding to this is  $x^4- 4x^2 +2$, this has $4$ roots

$\pm \sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt{2}}$

Now, I know that the Galois Group will contain $4$ elements and to prove that it is cyclic it is enough to produce an automorphism of order $4$.

Beyond this stage I am totally lost, I don't really get how exactly do we define the automorphisms in these kinds of problems, although the questions has been answered here [Galois Group of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575171/galois-group-of-sqrt2-sqrt2-over-mathbbq) still I don't get why did we define $f(\sqrt{(2+ \sqrt2)}) =  \sqrt{2 -\sqrt2}$ only. Why can't it map to any other element?

It would be very helpful if someone can clear these doubts.

Thank You.

Comment: @markvs The op has already linked it in his question.  The Op is having trouble in understanding why the answer only chose $f$ to map $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ to $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ and not anything else.

Comment: I know. What the OP wants to find out is already explained in the answer to the linked question: "We can determine the nature of $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ by the order of each element.  If $f$ is a field automorphism on $F$ and $f(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2})=\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$, then $f(\sqrt 2)=f(\alpha^2-2)=f(\alpha)^2-2=-\sqrt 2$.  Therefore $$f(f(\alpha))=f\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}\right)=f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}}\right)=\frac{f(\sqrt 2)}{f(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2})}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}=-\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}$$

Therefore $\mathrm{ord}(f)> 2$..., so $\mathrm{ord}(f)=4$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many choices do you have to map $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ ? Well you obviously have the identity map $1$.

You can map it to $-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$. In that case $\sigma : \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\mapsto -\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ .

$\sigma^{2}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})= -\sigma(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\implies \sigma^{2}=1$ (identity).

So $\sigma^{2}=1$ is of order hence $|\sigma|=2$

So this cannot generate a cyclic group of order $4$.

Also you can map $\tau(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$.

In that case again following what it did in the linked answer you can prove that $|\tau|>2$.

The key fact is that there are only two groups of order $4$ upto isomorphism. The Klein 4 group which is not cyclic ( hence every element is of order $2$) and the Cyclic group of order $4$. Since you have already found an element of order $>2$. You can conclude that $Gal(\Bbb{Q}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}/\Bbb{Q})\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{4\mathbb{Z}}$ .

Also it is first critical to prove that $\Bbb{Q}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{4}-4x^{2}+2$ to at all conclude that the extension is indeed Galois . To do that you need to do as the answer in the link does .

$$\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{\sqrt 2 \cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}}{\sqrt{4-2}}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$$
And say that all roots of the polynomial are in this extension.

Comment: So basically we are using the fact that if $\alpha$ is a root of minimal polynomial then $f(\alpha)$ is also the root of that polynomial, and thereby we are defining these automorphisms. Thank you, this made things a lot more clearer.

Comment: Exactly. If $\alpha$ is a root of the minimal polynomial then apply $\sigma$ to $p(\alpha)$ and you will get $p(\sigma(\alpha))=0$. So $\sigma$ should permute the roots of the minimal polynomial .